# Java - Graphical glitches on background repaint

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm making a microwave simulation program and having an annoying problem. I want the microwaves viewing window to change color on a button press, to visualize that the microwave is on. However, because I also have a jlabel with an icon (food image) in the background, I need the background to be semi transparent. I've accomplished this adding an alpha value to the jPanel (cookingWindow).

It starts like this [image]

So what I've basically done is set an actionEvent to the start button with the following code.
    `cookingWindow.setBackground(new Color (250,234,1, 150));
 cookingWindow.repaint();`

This works, except this happens [image]

When I minimise and maximise the window, everything goes back to place. But obviously, it would be preferable if you didn't have to minimise the window. Any ideas on how to stop this visual bug?

Answer (score 3):

See [Backgrounds With Transparency](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/31/backgrounds-with-transparency/) for an explanation of the problem and a couple of solutions.

Basically the problem is how the Swing opaque property handles transparent backgrounds (it doesn't).

Comment: Thanks for the link. The part that confuses me is that when I minimise and maximise the window, it works exactly how I want it too. Why is that?

Comment: @user2773084 This will gave something to do with the order in which components are painted

Comment: @user2773084, probably because the entire frame gets repainted, so all child components get painted in order so the backgrounds are painted properly. However when you update your label, only the label gets repainted since it is opaque.

Answer (score -1):

Revalidating and repainting the jFrame seems to do fix everything up. I was previously only repainting the jPanel.

Comment: -1, Not the proper solution. Your code is breaking the painting contract between swing components. I see you didn't read the link I provided in the blog that goes into further detail on how painting works. Don't take shortcuts.

Comment: Repainting usually resolves the glitching problems in swing +1